# Read HTTP headers in Controller (Zend Framework)

Tags: php, zend-framework, http-headers

Long story short: 
I'm building a skeleton application for Zend Framework and I got to the part where I need to setup the `api` module. I'm using `Zend_Rest_Controller` for this job. All is ok up to this part where I need to get the HTTP headers in a controller to verify the api key.

On various tutorials I've read on the web the thing is done via a front controller plugin, but I need it to be more "plug and play" than that (checking each time the config of the application, deciding which module is the api and so on).

I tried what seemed most obvious `$this->getRequest()->getHeaders()` but doesn't seem to work, at least not for the HTTP headers where I'll be seding my api key. Neither the `reponse` object.

Can anyone help me with this one?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found a way of doing this after all :)

On the `preDispatch()` method in your controller you can do the following:

```
public function preDispatch()
{
    $request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
    $key = $request->getHeader('x-apikey');
}
```

It seems that `Zend_Controller_Request_Http` object gives you acces to the headers. More info on the `Zend_Controller_Request_Http` you can find [here](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Controller/Request/Zend_Controller_Request_Http.html)

Comment: I've dug deep into the annals of Zend history and found this nugget. This totally saved my butt today. Thank you good sir, thank you.

Answer (score 10):

As Bogdan said, you can find that information in the Zend_Controller_Request_HTTP class. It can be found in the controller itself by doing :

```
$this -> getFrontController() -> getRequest() -> getHeader('Content-Type');
```

Unfortunatly, you can't access all headers at once but what ZF does is just use apache_request_headers() function if available on the server to get them.

Comment: When I run this from a subclass of `Mage_Customer_AccountController` the result is a fatal error: `Call to undefined method Namespace_Module_AccountController::getFrontController() `. I'm using Magento v 1.9.1.0.

Comment: @quickshiftin - of course - because these are methods of Zend Framwork and Magento doesn't have them.